# Locked/unlocked session check and last input

Tags: c++, session, winapi

I've managed to get all my sessions using WTSEnumerateSessions but I cant figure out how to get their status locked/unlocked and in case they're unlocked get the time since last input . Any tips / help ?

Answer (score 2):

To get a session's lock state:

- On Windows 7 and later, you can use [`WTSQuerySessionInformation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationw) with its `WTSInfoClass` parameter set to [`WTSSessionInfoEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ns-wtsapi32-wtsinfoexw).
- On older systems, you would have to monitor lock/unlock events in real-time using [`WTSRegisterSessionNotification()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsregistersessionnotification) to receive [`WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/wm-wtssession-change) notifications, checking its `wParam` for `WTS_SESSION_LOCK` and `WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK` status codes.

To get a session's last input time:

- On Vista SP1 and later, you can use [`WTSQuerySessionInformation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationw) with its `WTSInfoClass` parameter set to [`WTSSessionInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ns-wtsapi32-wtsinfow).
- On older systems, you would have to use [`CreateProcessAsUser()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) to run a helper process inside the target session, which can then call [`GetLastInputInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo) and communicate that info back to your main app.